# Is kuzushiji considered archaic?

Tags: words, handwriting

I am wondering if it is a necessary skill to learn how to read and write kuzushiji in modern japanese.

Answer (score 7):

Moderate *kuzushiji* style based on modern orthographical standard (like [this](http://pds.exblog.jp/pds/1/201001/01/47/b0172747_19595829.jpg) or [this](http://blog-fino.cocolog-nifty.com/photos/uncategorized/photo_23.jpg)) is widely accepted and well understood. Some people are actually fond of writing in such style, so maybe you'll need to learn how to read them in private letters and fancy cards.

Meanwhile, hardcore historical *kuzushiji* stored in archives and museums (like [this](http://su-cultural-history.up.n.seesaa.net/su-cultural-history/image/P1030717.JPG?d=a48) or [this](https://ks.c.yimg.jp/res/chie-que-10135/10/135/309/910/i320)) is totally different and basically incomprehensible to today's people without proper training. Students of Japanese history or philology have to start with learning to decipher those characters. They are, like old German handwriting, definitely archaic.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether it's technically considered archaic, but unless you're working at a museum, I don't think you'd even need to know how to read kuzushi-ji, let alone write it. It would be a cool skill to have, but you'll never need it in day-to-day life. I lived over there for about a year and have worked as a translator for seven, and the only kuzushi-ji I've seen so far was on a plaque on an old monument.